# why my slide(carousel) doesn't have an area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**This is my html code in body**

```
<main>
    <div class="slide_container">
        <!-- radio buttons -->
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
        <!-- slide images -->
        <div class="slide first">
            <img src="{% static 'images/slide/test1.PNG' %}">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="{% static 'images/slide/test2.PNG' %}">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="{% static 'images/slide/test3.PNG' %}">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="{% static 'images/slide/test4.PNG' %}">
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="sub_banner">WHY WHY</div>
    <div class="main_banner">why! my slide(carousel) doesn't have an area?</div>
    <div class="sub_banner">why!!! my slide(carousel) doesn't have an area?</div>
</main>
```

**my css code**

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
body{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: grey;
    line-height:1;
}
.main{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider{
    width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.slide_container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 500%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}
.slide_container input{
    display: none;
}
.slide{
    width: 20%;
    transition: 1s;
}
.slide img{
    width: 640px;
    height: 430px;
}
```

I want to make a product area under the slide, but it's not visible because it's covered by the slide.
like this
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdyNw.png)

How can I create a product area just below the slide?
i tried using **display: block** and i checked every tag is closed + I didn't use **float:left**

I pulled these codes out of the main tag. but nothing has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's causing your problem is the `position: absolute` in your `slide_container` css rule, removing that caused [this result](https://prnt.sc/wmpsin) (I don't have the images of course). You should either remove that or change to `position: relative`

Edit:

[A quick reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for why this happens

> **Absolute:**
> *The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout*. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
> This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. The margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not collapse with other margins.

Comment: what a perfect explanation! Thank you so much  :)